# Telebot package problem with importing "Types"

Tags: python, wxpython, telegram, telegram-bot, python-telegram-bot

When i want to run my bot in pycharm, I receive this error:

```
\Desktop\st\taxi\taxi.py", line 5, in <module>
    from telebot import types
ImportError: cannot import name 'types' from 'telebot' (C:\Users\User\Desktop\st\taxi\venv\lib\site-packages\telebot\__init__.py)
```

Here is my code:

```
import config
from telebot import TeleBot, types

bot = TeleBot(config.TELEGRAM_BOT_TOKEN)

@bot.message_handler(commands=['location']) #Запрос локации
def request_location(message):
    keyboard = types.ReplyKeyboardMarkup(row_width=1,      resize_keyboard=True)

    button_geo = types.KeyboardButton(text="Отправить местоположение", request_l
ocation=True)
    keyboard.add(button_geo)
    bot.send_message(message.chat.id, "Поделись местоположением", reply_markup=k
eyboard)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    bot.polling()
```

How to fix this?

Comment: Python version ??

Comment: my version  python 3.7

Comment: This API is tested with Python 2.6, Python 2.7, Python 3.4, Pypy and Pypy 3. Hence change your Python version

Comment: This posting on GitHub: https://github.com/eternnoir/pyTelegramBotAPI/issues/323 suggests that this is a common problem that can be resolved by uninstalling `telebot` and installing `pytelegrambotapi`. I don't understand the relationship between the two. This might not be the best advice.

Comment: These ways are not working